# Parsing Haskell file with CPP macros fails

Tags: parsing, haskell, macros

I am using [GHC 9.0.2](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_9_0_2.html) and I am trying to compile a file like this with [haskell-src-exts-1.23.1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.23.1):

```
Main.hs
~~~~~~~
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

module Main where

#define MSG "Hello world!"

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn MSG
```

The basic compilation with compiler works just fine: `ghc Main.hs`. But try to do the same with [`parseFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.23.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts.html#v:parseFile):

```
ghci> import Language.Haskell.Exts
ghci> parseFile "Main.hs"
ParseFailed (SrcLoc "Main.hs" 5 1) "Parse error: #"
```

Even using `parseFileWithExts [EnableExtension CPP] "Main.hs"` gives the same result.

So the question is: how to parse Haskell files with CPP macros inside of them?

Comment: hse doesn't run preprocessor for you. You either run it manually or by the means of another package called hse-cpp, which is very dated though.

Comment: In general, hse is not maintained, and whatever you wanted to use it for, you better try to employ the ghc-lib-parser package.

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn Thanks for the info, now please submit an answer so that I can accept it. Or, if you prefer, I could submit it.

Comment: Give me a little time to formulated a proper SO answer with an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`haskell-src-exts` in itself is not concerned with calling the preprocessor, so the parser fails when it sees syntax of the preprocessor (`#define...`). There's a separate package that wraps a call to the preprocessor — `hse-cpp`. With the `Main.hs` as in the question, this works:

```bash
$ cabal install --lib  haskell-src-exts hse-cpp --package-env=.
...
$ ghci
...
> import Language.Haskell.Exts
> import Language.Haskell.Exts.CPP
> parseFileWithCommentsAndCPP defaultCpphsOptions defaultParseMode "Main.hs"
ParseOk (Module ...
```